# Limit to 2 decimal places with a own pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

I have found an example which limits a number to 2 decimal places
{{ 300000| number : '1.2-2'}}
I gets the following result 3,000.00. But I would like the following result with space  3 000.00.
Is there a simple pipe ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in `pipe` for that, but you can create a custom pipe that will replace the `,` elements with whatever separator you like

```js
@Pipe({ name: "stringReplace" })
class StringReplacePipe {
  transform(val: string, target: string, replaceValue: string) {
    return val.toString().replaceAll(target, replaceValue);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>{{3000 | number:'1.2-2'| stringReplace:",":" " }}</h1>
```